# Validate JSON Schema properties with at least one containing specific value

Tags: json, jsonschema

I would like to know if I can define a JSON schema (draft 4) that requires at least one of many properties to have a specific value.

To illustrate, here is an example JSON I expect to *FAIL* the validation:

```
{
    "daysOfWeek": {
        "mon": false,
        "tue": false,
        "wed": false,
        "thu": false,
        "fri": false,
        "sat": false,
        "sun": false
    }
}
```

But if any (one or more) of the above properties is set to `true`, only then I'd expect it to *PASS* the validation.

So what would the Schema be?

```
{
    "daysOfWeek": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "mon": { "type": "boolean" },
            "tue": { "type": "boolean" },
            "wed": { "type": "boolean" },
            "thu": { "type": "boolean" },
            "fri": { "type": "boolean" },
            "sat": { "type": "boolean" },
            "sun": { "type": "boolean" }
        },
        "anyOf": [{
            // ?
        }]
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Jason's answer is good (and readable) for the case you have here.  In the general case (where you might have arbitrary numbers of properties), there's a more concise way (but less readable):

You could rephrase your requirement as "The properties are not all allowed to be false", in which case a schema could be:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {...},
    "not": {
        "additionalProperties": {"enum": [false]}
    }
}
```

The `additionalProperties` is in a sub-schema, so it's not connected to the `properties` value at the root level.  It therefore applies to *all* the properties.

The subschema inside `not` will only pass if all properties are `false` - therefore the outer schema will only pass if *not* all the properties are `false`.

Comment: This answer has advantage in that it does not require you to know all possible values of the key name (if the case is different than daysOfWeek).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `enum` keyword to specify that a property has a specific value.  You can combine that trick with `anyOf` to get the desired validation behavior.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "daysOfWeek": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "mon": { "type": "boolean" },
        "tue": { "type": "boolean" },
        "wed": { "type": "boolean" },
        "thu": { "type": "boolean" },
        "fri": { "type": "boolean" },
        "sat": { "type": "boolean" },
        "sun": { "type": "boolean" }
      },
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "mon": { "enum": [true] }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "tue": { "enum": [true] }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "wed": { "enum": [true] }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "thu": { "enum": [true] }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "fri": { "enum": [true] }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "sat": { "enum": [true] }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "sun": { "enum": [true] }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know I'm not suppose to simply say "thanks" but I have to because that is precisely what I had in mind and you nailed it. But I'm "accepting" cloudfeet answer as it is helping me think out of the box by looking at the same problem from a different angle... So +1 and thank you Jason!